# php / apache, is there any way to block cross domain post

Tags: php, apache, post

I have some ajax page with php post (so that CAPTCHA is not a good idea).

some `fsockopen` or `curl` could set `POST value` to steel data with cross domain.

So php / apache, is there any way to block cross domain post?

Comment: Steal what? Bytes? You can not steal bytes at all. You must explain better what your issue is. If you don't want other to request your website you need ask for a password first and then give only the password to those you want to.

Comment: @hakre, I have some query from `yahoo boss api`, i doubt some guy use `fsockopen` or `curl` steel my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are publishing the data. You can't stop people requesting it.

If you want to keep it secret, require authorisation before allowing access.

There are various barriers you can put in people's way—while still keeping the data public—but none of them are difficult to bypass. Testing the user agent doesn't stop the requestor specifying a user-agent that matches a common browser. Requiring a cookie from another page on your site doesn't stop them requesting that page and getting a cookie for their tool. Etc.

Comment: basic auth sends passwords in plain text and anyone with charles web proxy or a similar browser plugin can sniff your login and password, then write their own script to spam you.  The only way to stop this is to use SSL to make the request.  If you server does not have SSL installed, it might cost $$ or you'll have to generate your own self-signed certification.   Using a self-signed cert might prompt your browser to accept the certification, which scares a lot of users away.

Comment: I said nothing about "basic auth" just auth. People using Charles of a browser plugin are people who you have authorised to use the service. You can't stop them from finding out the password. Even if you encrypt the connection (which is a good idea, in general, whenever you are doing anything requiring a login) then they either know the password or can get the password from the source code you send to the browser.

Comment: If you are going to perform authentication/authorisation for this then you need to use criteria more stringent than "Has visited the website" so the credentials can't be taken from what you send to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

A lot web services that offer an API, but don't want just any old person to access the API, use public / private keys via CURL.  You would have to do a little research on public / private key encryption if you are not familiar.  I am sure there are PHP libraries that get all if not most of this done for you.

Credit card merchants like Authorize.net, and several customer database services that handle PII (Personally Identifiable Information) that I've worked with over the years allow you to post to a URL and retrieve the result.  They protect their services using public / private key encryption.  They issue me a key and I have to post that key along with my request data.  The key is usually sent in a header, hence the need to use CURL.

**Background Information:**
http://computer.howstuffworks.com/encryption3.htm

**PHP Examples:**
http://www.joeldare.com/wiki/php:php_public_private_key_cryptography

Note: the benefit of this system is that *you have absolute control over who is allowed to post to the PHP script* on your server.   If you don't need that level of control, you can just use something called "http basic auth".  Place your sensitive scripts in a directory and protect it with .htaccess authentication. Here is a tool to get you started.  http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-authentication/

When you make requests via ajax (jquery, I take it) you can pass the login and password.  Just make sure you use an SSL connection in your ajax (HTTPS).  Otherwise, people can sniff out your login and password as it will be sent in plain text without the use of SSL.

If you do use basic auth instead of public/private keys, your domain will need an SSL cert if it does not already have one.  You can buy one from someplace like Thawte.com (not cheap), or self-sign your own certificate. However, if you're going to go through all that trouble, you're 80% to the point of just going the public/private key encryption route.  Self-signed certificates usually prompt the user's browser with a warning.  This scares away a lot of people.

Comment: That's … overcomplicated. For most cases, passwords and SSL would do for authentication and protection of data in transit. With this solution, how would you go about handling the JavaScript side of the cryptography?

Comment: SSL is fine.  However basic httpauth sends passwords in plain text and can be sniffed.  Basic auth would work, just so long as he makes sure to only accept SSL connections and ignore the un-encrypted requests.

Comment: @mrbinky3000 , my site has ssl (https://), is an ajax post to a `https://` be safe?

Comment: @cj333 — Safe? Yes. Although you still need to give people usernames/passwords first. You might have trouble using HTTP Basic Auth with XMLHttpRequest, I've not tried it, and might have to use a cookie based approach instead.